Composer installation for Drupal module failed
I am trying to install Commerce POS on a fresh Drupal 10 installation but composer is showing an error !
Steps I went through

Install latest Drupal 10 version (10.3.10) via composer using:
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:^10 "example.com"

Visit example.com on my browser to finish Drupal initial installation

Install and enable Inline Entity Form Module using:
composer require 'drupal/inline_entity_form:^3.0@RC'

Install and enable Commerce Module and all its sub-modules using:
composer require 'drupal/commerce:^3.0@beta'


Until now all is working as expected until I tried to install Commerce POS module using:composer require 'drupal/commerce_pos:^3.0@alpha'
All I am getting is below error:
user@example.com [~/public_html/pos.example.com]# composer require 'drupal/commerce_pos:^3.0@alpha'
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drupal/commerce_pos
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/commerce_pos ^3.0@alpha -> satisfiable by drupal/commerce_pos[3.0.0-alpha1, 3.0.0-alpha2, 3.0.0-alpha3].
    - drupal/commerce_pos[3.0.0-alpha1, ..., 3.0.0-alpha3] require drupal/commerce_pos_keypad * -> satisfiable by drupal/commerce_pos_keypad[2.0.0, ..., 2.6.0].
    - drupal/commerce_pos_keypad[2.0.0, ..., 2.6.0] require drupal/commerce_pos ^2 -> found drupal/commerce_pos[2.0.0-alpha1, ..., 2.6.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.0@alpha).


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Any help please to by pass this error ?
Below is the content of my composer.json file:
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^2.0",
        "drupal/commerce": "^2.40",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10.3",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^10.3",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^10.3",
        "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^3.0@RC"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "phpstan/extension-installer": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}


What is the output of composer prohibits drupal/commerce_pos 3.0.0?

@jaypan after running the above command:
In BaseDependencyCommand.php line 103:
Could not find package "drupal/commerce_pos" in your project

It fails because there’s no compatible version of a module called commerce_pos_keypad. If you aren’t requiring that module, directly, this is presumably a bug in the commerce_pos module 3.0 branch itself. Probably to be expected, it is only in alpha. Downgrading to 2.x might be your only option until the bug is fixed (if that branch is compatible with everything else), otherwise check the issue queues for known issues and any relevant patches

The only downgrading available is for Drupal 8 version and our website is built using Drupal 10 version... I have tried all versions compatible with D10 with all same errors.

Yeah, looks the commerce pos module is pretty much abandoned. There’s been no code changes or maintainer engagement for a year or so now
